# How do you size a d3js graph to fit as a percentage and have the right aspect ratio?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Basically, I am trying to make this code fit into a div on a page with attributes of 100% for both width and height so nothing gets cut off, and while it fits, information gets cut off especially in the X-axis.

```
let margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50}
  , width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right // Use the window's width 
  , height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom; // Use the window's height

// The number of datapoints
let n = 21;

// 5. X scale will use the index of our data
let xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, n-1]) // input
    .range([0, width]); // output

// 6. Y scale will use the randomly generate number 
let yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 1]) // input 
    .range([height, 0]); // output 

// 7. d3's line generator
let line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d, i) { return xScale(i); }) // set the x values for the line generator
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.y); }) // set the y values for the line generator 
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX) // apply smoothing to the line

// 8. An array of objects of length N. Each object has key -> value pair, the key being "y" and the value is a random number
let dataset = d3.range(n).map(function(d) { return {"y": d3.randomUniform(1)() } })

// 1. Add the SVG to the page and employ #2
let svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .attr("width", '100%')
    .attr("height", '100%')
    .attr('viewBox','-22 20 '+Math.min(width,height)+' '+Math.min(width,height))
    .attr('preserveAspectRatio','xMinYMin')
    .append("g")


// 3. Call the x axis in a group tag
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)); // Create an axis component with d3.axisBottom

// 4. Call the y axis in a group tag
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale)); // Create an axis component with d3.axisLeft

// 9. Append the path, bind the data, and call the line generator 
svg.append("path")
    .datum(dataset) // 10. Binds data to the line 
    .attr("class", "line") // Assign a class for styling 
    .attr("d", line); // 11. Calls the line generator 

// 12. Appends a circle for each datapoint 
svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(dataset)
  .enter().append("circle") // Uses the enter().append() method
    .attr("class", "dot") // Assign a class for styling
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return xScale(i) })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d.y) })
    .attr("r", 5)
      .on("mouseover", function(a, b, c) { 
            console.log(a) 
        this.attr('class', 'focus')
        })
      .on("mouseout", function() {  })
```

On the X-axis numbers are cut off to about 10, but the y values look almost okay. How can I make it so that all of the information on both the x and y axis doesnt get cut off?

This is the example line graph for D3js V5.

Thanks.

Comment: bigger left margin maybe?

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle or codepen with sample data and html for review.